# How to submit two forms at a time and store first form submit output value as 2nd form value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Using the below form 1, i'm generating a goo.gl short url inline in #shortUrlInfo area. I want to use the generated short url in 2nd form to save it in wordpress custom field.

Form 1:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input style="display:none;" type='text' id='longUrl' value='<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'longurl', true ); ?>' /> 
<input name="shorturlinput" type="button" id="shortIt" value="Short It" /></form> 

<div class="info" id="shortUrlInfo"></div>
```

Form 2:

```
<?php
global $post;
if( isset($_POST['submit_meta']) ) {
if( ! empty($_POST['change_meta']) ) {
   update_post_meta($post->ID, 'shorturl', $_POST['change_meta']);
}}
?>


<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="change_meta" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_meta" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How can i submit the first form and pass the generated short url to 2nd form and submit that short url value in custom field with one click?

Or atleast, how can we display the generated short url in 2nd form input, which if we click on submit button, it should save in database.

It's my first question here & I've tried my best to find answer before posting here with no luck.

Comment: Those two forms are working if i input the data in 2nd form, but i want to auto submit the 2nd form input with 1st form output data.

I'm looking for a solution, If all this process works with just one click.

Comment: In my deleted answer I added an autosubmitted form with JavaScript. Maybe that's what you need, a form that autosubmits after one second or something.

Comment: Done! I edited my answer and added your code mixed with my code. Check it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Next example code shows how to achieve what I believe you want (with one click!). Explanation first: one form (file #1) sends a text to a script (file #2), this script redirects to another form (file #3), this form gets the original text and automatically resend it to another script (file #4) that inserts it in database, next image explains it better:

[image]

As you can see, the text in the first form becomes a value for the second form.

Now the code. In order to test next code, you will have to create four text files and give them the given names (if you change the filenames, you will have to change the "action" property in the forms), ***copy-paste my code in your files***, then, open you browser and run only the first file like this) :

```
http://localhost/form_sequence_1.php
```

These are the files:

**form_sequence_1.php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    FORM 1
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="form_sequence_2.php">
      Enter a text
      <input type="text" name="my_text" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Send text" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**form_sequence_2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[ "my_text" ] = $_POST[ "my_text" ];
header( "Location: form_sequence_3.php" );
?>
```

**form_sequence_3.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function autosendform () {
setTimeout( "sendform()","3000" );
}
function sendform () {
document.getElementById( "my_form" ).submit();
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="autosendform();">
    FORM 2
    <br/>
    <form method="post" action="form_sequence_4.php" id="my_form">
      Text entered in previous form
      <input type="text" name="my_text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[ "my_text" ]; ?>"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="AUTOSENDING FORM IN 3 SECONDS" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**form_sequence_4.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION[ "my_text" ] . " succesfully inserted into database.";
?>
```

More explanations:

- Value in form 1 sends the text to form 2.
- In the middle of form 1 and form 2 we need a script to capture the value.
- Form 2 automatically resends the value thanks to a timer in JavaScript.
- The last script gets the value and insert it in database (not for real).

*The advantage of this approach is that the scripts allow you to do many things with the value or values, like validating or conversion.*

Next is your code with my JavaScript timer code adapted :

```
<?php
global $post;
if ( isset($_POST['submit_meta']) )
   if ( ! empty($_POST['change_meta']) )
      update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'shorturl',$_POST['change_meta'] );
?>

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function autosendform () {
setTimeout( "sendform()","3000" );
}
function sendform () {
document.getElementById( "my_form" ).submit();
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="autosendform();">

<form method="post" action="" id="my_form">
  <input type="text" name="change_meta" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit_meta" value="Submit" />
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well its all ajax . you need to post your data with ajax function to the controller which save the shortened url in data base , how ? like this :

give your second form  + the first input of your second form 2 ids

```
$("#shortIt").click(function(){
  var longUrl = $('#longUrl').val()
  $.post("ur_url.php",
  {
      "longUrl": longUrl // here the url will be sent to your server and server communicates 
      // with goo.gl url shorter by its api and respond you with a variable called data
  },
  function(data, status){ // your server send here the shorturl and this function calls it
      //also this function will be run after the server respond is completed
      $('#inputID').val(data) // data will be set inside the input value
      document.getElementById("#SecondForm").submit(); // your second form submits and your
      // server needs to get the data and save it in your data base
  });
});
```

all will be done with a single click .

also you can do many things when the process is going on . but i hope i gave you some clue :P

Comment: Thanks for the response. But,

It's not doing anything, i gave id to 2nd form as metaform & 2nd form -> 1st input as metainput.

But when i clicked on short it button of first form, it's just giving me the same old output. It's not submitting 2 forms at a time and storing the short url in post meta using the 2nd form.

-- Update : When i've added the above code in between 2 forms, it has copied entire html of the page to the 2nd form input.

Comment: you need 2 pages to handle your post methodes , first is the one will short your url ( the page consist of url shortner api -> you need to use it ) , then your server will respond with data , and data is the short url and '$('#inputID').val(data)' will put data in the second form then 'document.getElementById("#SecondForm").submit();' will submit your form to where ever you order your form.

Comment: Ohh, But i need it in a single page. Is there any way that, once the short url generated, it directly goes to post meta and save automatically?

Comment: I eddited my Post , and tried to explain more , check it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this in HTML:

```
<form (return to script)>
    <input 1>
</form>
    <input 2>
```

---

Then in script:

```
get input 1 and input 2
```